# XCode7.2 keep crash

Tags: xcode, crash, xcode7.2

My XCode7.2 keep crash after open an project. 
Below is the crash report. Any suggestion?
I think it's similar to [Why does xCode crash when I open a project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19935904/why-does-xcode-crash-when-i-open-a-project)

```
Process:               Xcode [4687]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               7.2 (9548)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-9548000000000000~7
App Item ID:           497799835
App External ID:       814662604
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Xcode [4687]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2016-01-05 12:02:36.156 +0800
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.11.2 (15C50)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        D6E08775-0376-D30A-1EFE-52215D842578


Time Awake Since Boot: 640 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        20  <DBGLLDBSessionThread (pid=8728)>  Dispatch queue: DVTInvalidationPreventionQueue

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

VM Regions Near 0:
--> 
    __TEXT                 000000010cc40000-000000010cc44000 [   16K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 7C68
closed document

Global Trace Buffer (reverse chronological seconds):
367.387171   CFNetwork                  0x00007fff86157a5b TCP Conn 0x7fe55ddd0420 SSL Handshake DONE
368.100013   CFNetwork                  0x00007fff86157937 TCP Conn 0x7fe55ddd0420 starting SSL negotiation
368.100981   CFNetwork                  0x00007fff86156303 TCP Conn 0x7fe55ddd0420 complete. fd: 39, err: 0
368.101087   CFNetwork                  0x00007fff861e4b1d TCP Conn 0x7fe55ddd0420 event 1. err: 0
368.171468   CFNetwork                  0x00007fff861555d3 TCP Conn 0x7fe55ddd0420 started
368.221199   CFNetwork                  0x00007fff8611921a Creating default cookie storage with process/bundle identifier
368.221199   CFNetwork                  0x00007fff861191b2 Faulting in CFHTTPCookieStorage singleton
368.221199   CFNetwork                  0x00007fff86119041 Faulting in NSHTTPCookieStorage singleton
368.225091   CFNetwork                  0x00007fff86216654 NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1100

Thread 0:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Clean your derived data
2. Are yo using carthage by any chance ?
   Try to eliminate binaries by using carthage update --no-use-binaries.

Comment: Clean your derived data   And   Restart Computer looks like not resolve my problem.

Comment: And I have not give a try on the second suggestion. May be it will works.  But this problem not appear again for today.  I don't know why yet.

Comment: And yes, I use carchage.

Comment: I have fix one crash by carthage update --platform ios --use-submodules --no-use-binaries,  not sure why, but thanks any way.

Comment: I think the crash may be caused by lldb. Because the carthage is using downloaded binaries from the internet, the compiler doesn't have enough info on debugging and therefore causes the crash. "--no-use-binaries" I think you force carthage to compile the source libraries.